# Geofences triggering accurately only when Maps are open

Tags: android, android-geofence, google-location-services

I have built an app that triggers geofences defined in the app. But after a restart, it requires me to open Maps for obtaining the current location for it to generate the notification.

Can't post the code due to security reasons. Can someone tell me a way to do whatever Google Maps is doing to do with my app during start up.